# Sync Workday and SharePoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, workday-api

I am wondering if there is a way to sync workday calendars with SharePoint calendars.

Is there a way to sync the two calendars? like is there an API available for a workday that I can utilize to extract the calendar data such as employee leaves and populate it to a team site calendar?

or if not, I would want to create a SharePoint framework app and have a custom HTML calendar populated from workday's calendar.

I have tried getting a date from workday using SOAP but I am getting a CORS error.

Let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link, you have different options related absence

https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Absence_Management/v29.2/Absence_Management.html